# Crystal Reports SQL using multiple IN statements

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Table fields: patient_id, result_id, result_value

Result_IDs are:

- 19 = BP Diastolic
- 20 = BP Systolic
- 11408 = A1C
- 13731 = A1C
- 11379 = LDL
- 11515 = LDL
- 12134 = LDL

Query Examples:

```
Select from lab_observation LO
where LO.result_id in (19,20,11379,11515,12134,11408,13731)
```

Result:

```
patient_id    result_id    label           value 
123           19           BP Systolic     120
123           20           BP Diastolic    80
123           11379        LDL             1.2
123           11408        A1C             7.1
456           19           BP Systolic     120
456           20           BP Diastolic    80
```

I only want to see patient 123, however, when I change my query to:

```
Select * from lab_observation LO
where LO.result_id in (19,20) and LO.result_id in(11379,11515,12134) 
and LO.results_id in (11408,13731)
```

It doesn't return patient 123.

Here are the tables needed.

Tables:

Lab_observation:

```
observation_value    label        result_id    group_id
140                  BP-Systolic  19           1067613
90                   BP-Diastolic 20           1067613
.071                 A1C          11408        1067613
2.2                  LDL          11515        1067613
.08                  A1C          11408        1142318
```

Lab_observation_group:

```
group_id            patient_id
1067613             123
1142318             456
1042258             123
```

***group_id is unique. A patient_id does have multiple group_id in this table. Now that I think about this what I really want are the group_ids that have all four results.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM lab_observation_group a
 JOIN (    SELECT group_id 
      FROM lab_observation LO
      GROUP BY group_id 
      HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (19,20) THEN 1 END) = 1
         AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11379,11515,12134) THEN 1                         
        END)=1
         AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11408,13731) THEN 1 END) = 1
 )b
ON a.group_id = b.group_id
```

No results but I think this is close to what I need. Again thanks for everyone's assistance.

Comment: You're filtering on result id 3 times with an AND joining the clauses. The results id is only one value, it's impossible for it to be in those 3 groups at the same time.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment. Do you have a solution to my question? The unique key is the patient_id a patient listed in the lab_observation table does have results for multiple result_ids. I don't understand what you mean by in those 3 groups. I am not grouping the data.

Comment: If you want to filter for patient id, then filter for patient id. I'm not sure why you're trying to work around it by filtering on result_id. `LO.patient_id = 123`

Comment: What @Rabbit said is correct? What stopping you from filtering using patient id

Comment: I'm not saying you're "grouping" the data in the SQL sense of a GROUP BY clause. I'm saying your filter has split up the result ids into 3 separate groups of result ids. And since they're connected by an AND clause, it's impossible for it to be true.

Comment: There's only one `result_id` per row, `WHERE` filters at the individual row level, so no record can meet multiple conditions as you've defined them to be mutually exclusive, is another way of saying what @Rabbit said.

Comment: I don't know the patient_id until I query the results. What I am trying to find are all patients that have at least one result for the three result types.

Comment: @ChadMoore Then my answer is what you're after, to look for multiple conditions across rows you need either multiple queries, or the more efficient conditional aggregation inside the `HAVING` clause.  Not certain on syntax for crystal reports, but the idea is sound.

Comment: @HartCO Thanks again. I am trying to adapt your query but I didn't give you all the tables properly. the values for each result are in the lab_observation table. This is joined to the lab_observation_group table where the patient_id exists. I will try to create the query based on what you have taught so far. see my answer

Comment: @ChadMoore You should then be able to simply add the `JOIN` to the `FROM` section and keep the rest as is.

Comment: @HartCO I just updated my question with an adapted statement. It is still returning zero results.

Comment: Would the group id join 1:1 with patient ID? I'm guessing not, in which case you need to include the join to `lab_observation_group` in the subquery and change references to `group_id` in the subquery back to `patient_id`.

Comment: @HartCO You are correct there isn't a 1:1. In the lab_observation_group a single patient_id has multiple group_id. Each of the three results groups will have a group_id. I will update my question with my latest statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require that across multiple rows a set of conditions are met, you need to use aggregation, I don't know crystal reports syntax, but you can likely use conditional aggregates in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT patient_id 
FROM lab_observation LO
GROUP BY patient_id 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (19,20) THEN 1 END) = 1
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11379,11515,12134) THEN 1 END) = 1
  AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11408,13731) THEN 1 END) = 1
```

This will get you the `patient_id` values that meet this criteria, you can use it in a subquery to get the full records for these patients:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM lab_observation a
JOIN (    SELECT patient_id 
          FROM lab_observation LO
          GROUP BY patient_id 
          HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (19,20) THEN 1 END) = 1
             AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11379,11515,12134) THEN 1 END) = 1
             AND  MAX(CASE WHEN LO.result_id in (11408,13731) THEN 1 END) = 1
     )b
ON a.patient_id = b.patient_id
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what they want. They want the individual records, but just the records for the chosen patient.

Comment: @Rabbit Patient_ID 123 is the one that satisfies all the conditions, so I think that is what OP is after, but I added the subquery so they could see full detail for that patient.

Comment: That makes sense. I can see them wanting this over my interpretation. I guess they just need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You have an impossible condition in your WHERE. Let's simplify it a little bit to show you where you went wrong.

```
Select * from lab_observation LO
where LO.result_id in (19) and LO.result_id in (11379)
```

Basically, the query above is the same as

```
Select * from lab_observation LO
where LO.result_id = 19 and LO.result_id = 11379
```

This will never return any rows. The WHERE conditions are evaluated row by row. It is impossible for one row's result id to equal both those numbers.

If you want to filter for the records with those results ids in your first query and for patient 123, then that's what you filter on.

```
Select from lab_observation LO
where LO.result_id in (19,20,11379,11515,12134,11408,13731)
and LO.patient_id = 123
```